# ORA-29273: HTTP request failed intermittent error using the utl_http package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm using the `utl_http` package to make HTTP GET requests to an IIS site on the same server (local) as Oracle. Sometimes it works and I get the response, but more often than not it hangs for about 15 seconds and then I get this error:

> ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1722 ORA-29263: HTTP protocol error

As a test, I've got a small static text file in the IIS site, so this is how I'm testing it:

```
select utl_http.request('http://domain.com/test.txt') from dual
```

I get the same problem if I run it in Oracle Apex instead of direct on the db.

The other thing I've tried is to create a package of my own that does the HTTP request using the long `utl_htp.begin_request()` method, instead of the `utl_http.request()` shortcut. This gives the exact same problem (works sometimes but errors mostly - same error).

The pattern I'm seeing is if I wait a while and then try, it works for the first 2-10 times, and then begins erroring. When it does work, I get the response instantly and when it errors, there is always the delay before the error.

If I request the text file URL (or any other resource in the site) using a remote web browser then I get the correct response every time.

I have tried setting a timeout like below but it doesn't have any effect. For example instead of timing out after 3 seconds it continues for 10 or 15 seconds before the error is shown.

```
UTL_HTTP.set_transfer_timeout(3);
```

I think I can rule out ACL because it works sometimes.

Does anyone know what might cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons

-> You may have a problem with your TNS-Listener.

From the command prompt window, try to run `TNSPING service_name`   .. try to run it quickly several times and check if it fails in some of them.

I had once a similar problem. Try to re-configure your TNS-Listener.

There must be also an option in which you can give an IP number in the TNS-listener definition. This also solves sometimes these kind of problems.

-> IIS problem.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I've tried the TNSPING and it comes back `OK` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Read about SET_PERSISTENT_CONN_SUPPORT Procedure: 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm#i1027673

Using: utl_http.set_persistent_conn_support(true, 30);

Answer (score 0):

Could you be exceeding the limit of of concurrent HTTP connections? I vaguely remembering that I run into a similar problem when I forgot to close the HTTP connection.